# Convergence/divergence of the series $\sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac1{k(\ln k)^{1/2}}$ and $\sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac1{k(\ln k)^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

For the series
$$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} {1\over k(\ln k)^{1\over 2}}$$

$$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} {1\over k(\ln k)^{2}}$$
How would I prove that the first sequence diverges and the second converges. I tried to use partial sums but I don't know how to write the equations in the form needed to use the formula.
Thanks.

Comment: You can try using the integral test and then using the result about $p$-series

Comment: By the way, just for the sake of future reference: what you are looking at are specific case of *Bertrand series*, i.e. series of the form $\sum_{n} \frac{1}{n^a \ln^b n}$ (where $a,b$ are two constants). The general result states that such a Bertrand series converges if, and only if, (i) $a>1$ or (ii) $a=1$ and $b>1$.

Answer (score 1):

Integral test: $\displaystyle\int_{2}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{x(\log x)^{1/2}}dx=2\lim_{M\rightarrow\infty}(\log M)^{1/2}-2(\log 2)^{1/2}=\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT : consider $\int_{2}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x\log^{p}(x)}$ , where $p = 2$ or $p = 0.5$

Answer (score 0):

By the Cauchy Condensation test, the sum 
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty a_n
$$
converges if and only if 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}2^ka_{2^k}
$$
converges. 
For you first series, this means we may examine the sum of $\frac{2^k}{2^kk^{1/2}\ln 2}=\frac{1}{\ln 2k^{1/2}}$ converges, which it certainly does not. Do the same procedure for the second.